# Norm of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Would someone attempt to give me a simple explanation of how to compute the norm of an ideal. I like the definition |$O/a$| but find it difficult to apply. Perhaps the "determinant version" lends itself better to application. In any event, I need some hints for a problem which asks for all ideals of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{(-5)}]$ which contain the element $6$. The previous post with a similar title really doesn't address this issue clearly.

Comment: To contain is to divide. It therefore suffices to analyze the primes lying above 2 and 3, and put them together.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ This is easy if you write the ideal as a module in "normal" form,  e.g. see [section 2.3](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ant/ant02.pdf) in the nice exposition by Franz Lemmermeyer.

These normal forms generalize to higher degree number fields, e.g. see the discussion on Hermite and Smith normal forms in Henri Cohen's *A Course in Computational Number Theory*.